# What max_connection should I set for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, connection

I am using **MySQL 5.1.35** database on **Linux Centos**.

The Linux server has **2GB RAM with 14GB of disk space**.

I have created webservices using **Restlet** framework in Java which has **thousand** user access.

I want to set max_connection for maximum concurrent connections.

So please suggest me that what **`max_connection`** should I set?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why set it at all if you're not facing any problems?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to calculate the memory required by your MySQL engine. See manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-use.html)

If you are using MYISAM tables then you can calculate memory requirement using following formula:

```
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size) * max_connections = K bytes of memory
```

Ideally this should not exceed 2 GB in your case.

Configuration parameters depends on type of your application and querys, but standard values for you could be:

```
key_buffer_size = 1024MB + (read_buffer_size = 1MB + sort_buffer_size = 4MB) * 200 ~= 2GB
```

`key_buffer_size` is a global variables whereas `read_buffer_size and sort_buffer_size` are session level parameters.

Comment: Thanx Omesh for your good suggestion.
I calculated the variables - 
key_buffer_size  : 402653184 bytes
read_buffer_size : 65536 bytes
sort_buffer_size : 262144 bytes
max_connections  : 500

I got the value 553216 KB, so what max_connection beneficial for me?

Comment: 5GB is okay under normal load but if at a point if you get all the database requests equal to max number of connections then MySQL might get crashed so try to set these variables below 2GB. reducing the sieze of `read_buffer_size` & `sort_buffer_size` to 1MB and 4MB may help you increase performance. just try it.

Comment: Hi Omesh I'll try this. But is it 5GB or 540 MB? I am bit in confusion.

Answer (score 8):

This is dependent on the amount of memory you have and how your other settings are configured.  There's a [MySQL Calculator](http://www.mysqlcalculator.com/) you can use for this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give information like:

1. How many users using the application?
2. How many applications connect to the database?
3. What would be the load and how queries are given?

For server configuration:

1. It is better to have 2 separate servers for Apache/PHP and MySQL with the Linux of your choice.
2. Try not to run too much else on either box; leave the resources for Apache/PHP and MySQL.

You can get more info at [Tuning MySQL](http://www-css.fnal.gov/dsg/external/freeware/mysqlTuning.html).

Comment: Hi Praveen thanx for quick reply, there may be 100000 lac concurrent users, I have created 16 webservices all accesses the database.