# Why shouldn't I use max value for max_connections

Tags: mysql

On MySQL, is there any reason not to set max_connections to max value (100000)?

What would be the side effects of such approach?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12214511/3000179

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs:- Too many connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/too-many-connections.html):

> The number of connections permitted is controlled by the
>   max_connections system variable. The default value is 151 to improve
>   performance when MySQL is used with the Apache Web server.
>   (Previously, the default was 100.) If you need to support more
>   connections, you should set a larger value for this variable.
>
> mysqld actually permits max_connections+1 clients to connect. The
>   extra connection is reserved for use by accounts that have the SUPER
>   privilege. By granting the SUPER privilege to administrators and not
>   to normal users (who should not need it), an administrator can connect
>   to the server and use SHOW PROCESSLIST to diagnose problems even if
>   the maximum number of unprivileged clients are connected. See Section
>   12.7.5.30, “SHOW PROCESSLIST Syntax”.
>
> The maximum number of connections MySQL can support depends on the
>   quality of the thread library on a given platform, the amount of RAM
>   available, how much RAM is used for each connection, the workload from
>   each connection, and the desired response time. Linux or Solaris
>   should be able to support at 500 to 1000 simultaneous connections
>   routinely and as many as 10,000 connections if you have many gigabytes
>   of RAM available and the workload from each is low or the response
>   time target undemanding. Windows is limited to (open tables × 2 + open
>   connections) < 2048 due to the Posix compatibility layer used on that
>   platform.
>
> Increasing open-files-limit may be necessary. Also see Section 2.5,
>   “Installing MySQL on Linux”, for how to raise the operating system
>   limit on how many handles can be used by MySQL.

If you try to make more connection then what your system can support then eventually all those connections will be closed by default as your system configuration will not support it.